# Accessing Sharepoint Site from MVC App via CSOM both authetnicated via ADFS

Tags: model-view-controller, sharepoint, adfs, csom

I have created Sharepoint Application in  a Sharepoint on-premise environment that I configured to use ADFS as Authentication Provider. I have added the application in ADFS as relying party and successfully authenticate. 
Also I have created MVC Application and configured to use ADFS as Authentication Provider. Also I have added the application in ADFS as relying party and successfully authenticate.
In this moment the situation is follows:
- If I open the MVC application it redirects me to authenticate via ADFS. I enter windows credentials and I'm successfully logged in.
- I open the Sharepoint site and I'm already logged in (because I previously logged in via the Mvc App)
- If I log off from the MVC App I'm automatically logged off from Sharepoint.

The problem occurs when I'm trying to access the Sharepoint site in code via CSOM in the MVC Application.
I use the following code:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(delegate { return true; });

using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("https://portaladfs/"))
{
    Web web = context.Web;

    context.Load(web);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

When the code hits context.ExecuteQuery() it throws an error: 403 Forbidden Access

My Question is:
How can I make Identity Delegation so I can access the Sharepoint Site with the user that I'm currently logged in the MVC app via ADFS. 
I don't want to give explicit Network Credentials while I'm accessing the site because the users are pulled from Active Directory.
CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials or CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials is not an option because it gives me the account of the local pc (not the user from AD).

Please can you give me any suggestions or practical solution. I'm trying to solve this problem for a couple of days but with no success.

Thank you very much.
All the best,
Martin Kostovski